# How to check if a template is a class member of another template

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I made a function that sorts my vector by member (e.g. students by age or name) so I made a template function

```
template<class ElemType, class ElemMember>
void sort(vector<ElemType>& vec, ElemMember member, bool ascending = true)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < vec.size()- 1; ++j)
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size() - j - 1; ++i)
            if ((vec[i].*member < vec[i + 1].*member) ^ ascending)
                swap(vec[i], vec[i + 1]);
}
```

I want to add constraint that checks if `ElemType` is a class that has members and if my `ElemMember` is a member of that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a pointer to a data member of `ElemType`, as the parameter of `sort`, should suffice:

```
template <typename ElemType, typename MemberType>
void sort(std::vector<ElemType>& vec, MemberType ElemType::*member, bool ascending = true)
//                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd3316ece4ece759)

Comment: Beat me by seconds! Take your upvote :) https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3cuVQC

Comment: damn. If I only didn't stop to get a sip of my coffee.

Comment: Thank you! Should i make `const ElemMember ElemType::* const member` ?

Comment: @MaximYarmolik Template argument deduction will deduce `const` on its own if necessary (but in your case, you probably won't have const members at all). As for the second `const`, it's up to you.